# How to search all paths between two nodes in linked list Graph

Tags: c++

I make a graph using a list of adjacency-based multivariable list. I have sold all certain functions that create a data structure, but I can not realize the search of all possible routes between two points ((. I thought a lot, but could not figure out how to get all the ways, not just one. I know i have to use BFS, but i cant come up nothing(

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>


using namespace::std;

typedef string graphElement;

typedef struct vertexTag {
    graphElement data;
    int visited;

    struct edgeTag* edges;

    struct vertexTag* next;
    struct vertexTag* prev;
} vertexT;

typedef struct edgeTag {
    struct vertexTag* connectsTo;
    struct edgeTag* next;
} edgeT;

class graph {
private:
    vertexT* head;
    vertexT* tail;
    vertexT curr;
    int count_vertex;
    queue<vertexT*> queue;

    void BFS(graphElement destenetion, vertexT* startP);
    vertexT* FindVertex(graphElement data);

public:
    graph();
    ~graph();

    vertexT* AddVertex(graphElement data);
    void DeleteVertex(graphElement data);
    edgeT* AddEdge(graphElement source, graphElement destination);
    void DeleteEdge(graphElement source, graphElement destination);

    void PrintGraph();
    void DiskIn();
    void DiskOut();

    void FindAllPaths(graphElement source, graphElement destenetion);
 };
```

it is BFS i tryed to make((. I know its not so good :(

```
void graph::FindAllPaths(graphElement source, graphElement destenetion) {
    vertexT *vertP;
    vertexT *startP = NULL;

    for (vertP = head; vertP != NULL; vertP = vertP->next) {
        vertP->visited = 0;
        if (vertP->data == source)
            startP = vertP;
    }
    if (startP == NULL)
    {
        cout << "No such vertex";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        BFS(destenetion, startP);
    }

}

void graph::BFS(graphElement destenetion, vertexT* startP) {
    vertexT* current;
    edgeT* edgeP;
    vector<string>path;


    queue.push(startP);
    //startP->visited = true;

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        current = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        if (current->data == destenetion)
            copy(path.begin(), path.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
        for (edgeP = startP->edges; edgeP != NULL; edgeP = edgeP->next) {
            //if (!edgeP->connectsTo->visited) {
                queue.push(edgeP->connectsTo);
                edgeP->connectsTo->visited = true;
                path.push_back(edgeP->connectsTo->data);
        //  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your title is misleading. Your question is about the search on the graph, not deleting an edge, right?

Comment: oops yap you're right. It was old question ive done myself :)

Comment: You can use DFS instead of BFS, each time you reach the wanted vertex save that path, each path will be unique.

Comment: Do you want all paths or all mutually exclusive paths? Because if you search for all paths, you might end up many overlapping routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start = Pick any start node
search(start)

function search(node) {
  node.visited = yes
  for each vertex that has an edge to node (call it b): {
    if (b not visited) {
        search(b) // recursive call to search
    }
  }
}
```

If your graph does contain local groups of vertices not connected by any edge, this algorithm will fail to visit all. In that case, instead of `Pick any start node` you should iterate over all nodes and call `search`. Already visited root nodes will be skipped anyways. After the search, don't forget to reset the `visited` flag for all vertices!

**EDIT:**

As Михаил pointed out, this will only find one path. To find all possible paths: Every time you reach the target vertex you can save the route (you can keep a stack that gets passed on every recursive call, and vertices (or edges) added, popped like this:

```
start = pick your start vertex
target = pick your target vertex
stack = empty stack
search(start, start, target, stack)
resultingPaths = vector of stacks // here go all possible routes

function search(node, start, target, stack) {
  for each vertex that has an edge to node (call it b): {
    stack.push(b)
    if (b == target) {
      // we have found a path
      resultingPaths.add(a copy of stack)
    } else if (b != start) {
      // keep looking  
      search(b, start, target, stack) // recursive call to search
    }
    stack.pop()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it will find only 1 path, inst it :P?

Comment: Yes, thanks, @МихаилХамхоев it is correct. Updated the answer.

Comment: I thought you needed to keep track of visited vertices?